# Scala filtering tuple list

Tags: list, scala, filter, tuples

**Question : How do you filter based on other items in a list?**

I got a List that looks like that

```
List((2,2),(2,1),(3,1),....)
```

I want to keep the tupples which got the biggest second numbers when they got the same first ones

so something like that on output

```
List((2,2),(3,1),...)
```

with (2,1) removed because the 1 was < then 2  in (2,2)

so i need to filter based on other objects in the List how do you do that.

*Efficiency is not really important since the list got at maximum 171 items*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
for ((x, y) <- lst if !lst.exists(t => x == t._1 && y < t._2)) yield (x, y)
```

But if you want non-quadratic complexity:

```
lst.groupBy(_._1).map(_._2.max).toList.sorted
```

Comment: are you *quite* sure about that second example? groupBy will return a Map[Int,  (Int, Int)]

Comment: Someday I'll stop being surprised people would rather take a wild guess than paste a line into the repl.

Comment: extempore is right folk! The same goes for actually testing an answer before you accept it as well...

Comment: `lst.groupBy(_._1)` returns `scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, Int)]]`, not `Map[Int, (Int, Int)]`. I've tried both these in the repl before answering. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ahh, no...  I see what you're going now.  Grouping and then dropping the keys from the map - keeping only the max value for each key.  Manually doing what `.sorted.toMap` does anyway, but still pretty nifty.

Comment: Yeah - I agree, the `.sorted.toMap` solution is much more elegant. It didn't occur to me to rely on the `Map` semantics of keeping the last key.

Comment: Still, brutally de-keying a map like that.  It's a brave approach, and certainly one worth remembering.

Comment: Show no mercy to thy maps. :D

Answer (score 16):

Converting a list of pairs to a map will use the last occurring entry when a given "key" occurs twice.

And a Tuple is sorted on the first element, then the second element, etc.

So:

```
List((2,2),(2,1),(3,1)).sorted.toMap
// = List((2,1),(2,2),(3,1)).toMap
// = Map((2,2), (3,1))
```

Just convert back to a list with `.toList` afterwards, if necessary